# LinkedIn Group API changes

Tags: rest, linkedin-api

As far as I can tell, with the new changes to the API's, LinkedIn's Group api's are no longer public at all.  Are there any ways to access the posts made in a group without using the Group api?

All I'm looking to do is to read the posts from a public group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to access that API publicly any longer.  You would need to apply to be part of their partner program to get access to those endpoints once again:

https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs/apply

Comment: Thanks Justin, that's what I thought, but I was hoping I was missing something.  I had applied a while ago, and was denied (not entirely sure why, or what the requirements are to be approved for it)